# Converting annotated Spring Java classes back to XML

Tags: java, spring, performance

We have a large project consisting of hundreds if not thousands of beans that are mostly configured through component scanning. We have perhaps 20 component-scan tags for various packages and it does take quite a while to set up the context.

So as an experiment I decided to write a small program that would scan package directories for @component annotated beans and output a corresponding  definition. The idea was to see if using this (rather lengthy) xml definition was faster than all that component scanning.

Turns out it's not so simple to convert from annotations back to xml. Beans must be declared with their class (easy) and also their ID if one is defined (@component("id")) - also relatively easy. But there are also things like @Scope that must be taken into account, and probably other aspects I haven't thought of yet.

Two questions:

1) Is this all a wasted effort because component scanning is comparable in speed to a lengthy bean definition?

2) Do tools already exist that are able to perform this "conversion" for me - i.e. from annotated classes back to xml? I haven't been able to find one yet but I sure would prefer it.

Comment: If you want to explicitly define beans I would suggest using Java-based configuration rather than XML, it's a bit more expressive. Though I think you're probably better off spending your time figuring out why the scanning is taking so long: are there a lot of classes in your scan paths that aren't components?

Comment: I read many places that java configuration is also expensive - more so than even component scanning because of the bytecode rewriting that takes place. And yes there are annotated classes mixed with plain classes distributed across a wide range of packages. The xml file contains 18 component-scan tags right now, some are quite precise and others point to packages that have a lot of sub packages that also must be scanned. It takes 10+ seconds to initialize the full spring context which is a pain especially when testing.